# Static Landing Page Templates in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

If I create custom static HTML landing page templates using the Bootstrap framework, what is the best way to integrate those into an existing website within Wordpress?

My goal is to be able to quickly integrate custom PPC landing pages into WP sites without having to deal with the poorly coded websites I often face.

Here's are some thoughts I had and the problems I'm experiencing:

1. I could place a folder in the website's root directory that holds the files for the custom template (separate from Wordpress). The issue I'm facing is how to handle all of the form submissions / fills and how to push them to a Google spreadsheet or CRM.
2. I could create a custom page template within the existing theme and just dump the static HTML template in there. But how could I do this in a way that it has it's own CSS / Images and doesn't effect any other page on the website?

Is one method better than the other? What would you recommend?

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't an easy way.  If you are looking to integrate the Wordpress navigation system, footer, and page creation system then you will have to create  your templates using the Wordpress Theme Templating standard.

Start here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Because of the way Wordpress enqueues its style and javascript files, among many other reasons, not following the template system will cause updating issues as well as restrict the ability for certain added plugins to function in the future.

You will have to write your static bootstrap templates as Wordpress templates.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not really needing any of the navigation or footer functionality. When you say "write as Wordpress templates" are you meaning to create a custom page.php file using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes and no. You will need to create your static page following the Wordpress template format.  Read this page from top to bottom.  It is not a quick job. But once you understand it it is possible.

If you are not needing the header and footer etc.  You could try simply adding the `<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>` to the top of the static page, put the static page in the root of the template, then create a new page and assign the template you created to that page.  BUT this is a terrible thing and I am ashamed that I am suggesting it... sorry.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate your feedback. I'm still learning best practice for these types of things, so if it's a terrible thing to do, I'm thinking it's probably not worth my time to do it this way...

Comment: Really if you want to incorporate the static pages into the Worpdress CMS you need to create them as template files.  BUT I realized you could just put them in the root of the web directory and link to them directly. That would work. But you would have no control over their content in the CMS.

Comment: Right. I'm not too concerned about accessing content in the CMS, my only roadblock with that route is how to track form submissions. Ideally, I'd like to push them to a Google sheet doc. Do you know a simple way to do this?